# Update query for n number or rows

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

In my application I need to write one query which should update a single column of n number of rows. This n is depending on condition I am putting. What is the best way of handling this situation. I have seen some CASE ....WHEN ....THEN...Is there any better method?

```
id  store_id    store_name  client_id   client_name  
1   102         a          201          aa
2   102         b          201          bb
3   102         c          201          cc
4   105         d          201          dd
5   105         f          202          ee
6   101         g          202          ff
7   101         h          202          gg
8   101         i          202          hh
```

This the example i need to update store id to 210 and the condition is client_id =201

Comment: Question not clear

Comment: To prevent your question getting downvoted, include more details - Code and query that you tried, so we can better understand what you're asking

Comment: What do you mean by "update [...] n number of rows"?  An `UPDATE` usually comes with a `WHERE` clause which identifies the specific records to be updated.  How are you defining the logic of what records to update?

Comment: I have updated the question kindly have a look.

Comment: determine what the order by is, because you have introduced a limit concept

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE your_table SET store_id=210 where client_id=201;